# Enum DateOfWeek from .net to F# pattern match

Tags: .net, f#, pattern-matching

I get a warning for this function :

```
let dayofW' (d:System.DateTime) =
  match d.DayOfWeek with
  | DayOfWeek.Sunday    -> 0.0
  | DayOfWeek.Monday    -> 1.0
  | DayOfWeek.Tuesday   -> 2.0
  | DayOfWeek.Wednesday -> 3.0
  | DayOfWeek.Thursday  -> 4.0
  | DayOfWeek.Friday    -> 5.0
  | DayOfWeek.Saturday  -> 6.0
```

> Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example,
>   the value 'enum (7)' may indicate a case not covered by the
>   pattern(s).

I understand that I have to deal with Enum (and not DU) but I can't find a way. I could not find an "Enum pattern" in msdn language reference.

How could I remove the warning with the minimum overwork?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Simplest** way would be adding the ignoring pattern at the end:

```
let dayofW' (d:System.DateTime) =
  match d.DayOfWeek with
  | DayOfWeek.Sunday    -> 0.0
  | DayOfWeek.Monday    -> 1.0
  | DayOfWeek.Tuesday   -> 2.0
  | DayOfWeek.Wednesday -> 3.0
  | DayOfWeek.Thursday  -> 4.0
  | DayOfWeek.Friday    -> 5.0
  | DayOfWeek.Saturday  -> 6.0
  | _ -> 0.0 //Or throw an error, depends on how you wanna deal with this
```

It happens because even though you are listing every possible combination of the `DayOfWeek`enum, any numeric value can be casted to become an enum, so in theory `d.DayOfWeek` could have a value that is not listed in your pattern.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is, .NET enums aren't "strong". For example,

```
(DayOfWeek)42
```

is a perfectly valid value of the `DayOfWeek` enum.

This means that you *must* handle the other possible values as well, not only the "named" ones. Now, of course, `(DayOfWeek)42` shouldn't ever appear anywhere, so the proper response to a value like that could be an exception or some error value. But you still have to add it as another pattern:

```
| _ -> WhateverErrorValue
```

Comment: It's a mistake to say it's perfectly valid. It is storable, but it is not valid. As you say, it shouldn't appear and is an error. It should not be the responsibility of this part of the code to check for this error. Unfortunately F# is just not very good at working with enum types. For pure F# code that doesn't have to interact with other .Net code you can use Struct discriminated unions.